# Pandas dataframe mixed dtypes when reading csv

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

I am reading in a large dataframe that is throwing a `DtypeWarning: Columns` (I understand this warning) but am struggling to prevent it (I don't want to set `low_memory` to False as I would like to specify the correct dtypes.

For every columns, the majority of rows are float values and the last 3 rows are string (metadata basically, information about each column). I understand that I can set the dtype per column when reading in the csv, however I do not know how to change rows 1:n to be float32 for example and the last 3 rows to be strings. I would like to avoid reading in two separate CSVs. The resulting dtype of all columns after reading in the dataframe is 'object'. Below is a reproducible example. The dtype warning is not thrown when reading in i am guessing because of the size of the dataframe - however the result is exactly the same as the problem i am facing. i would like to make the first 3 rows float32 and the last 3 string so that they are the correct dtype. thank you!

reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 0.2,0.3],[0.1, 0.2,0.3],[0.1, 0.2,0.3],
                ['info1', 'info2','info3'],['info1', 'info2','info3'],['info1', 'info2','info3']],
                index=['index1', 'index2', 'index3', 'info1', 'info2', 'info3'], 
                    columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'] )
df.to_csv('test.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0)
```

Comment: `Series` need to be of a single dtype. If you require the first few values to be float and the last to be string, the only container you can use is `object`. But that's not advisable because it will cause complications with a lot of other data manipulations. Really you should rethink how you store the data, preferably in two separate DataFrames

Comment: Thank you - i thought this might be the answer - Would you advise reading in 2 dataframes, one with counts and with metadata? or is it safe to split them after being read in - and then doing a df1.astype('float32) and df2.astype('string') - i suppose what i was ultimately trying to avoid was reading in two separate dataframes...

Comment: It would probably be better to read it in separately, that way pandas will infer the dtypes properly and take advantage of a lot of the checks and protections of the import functions. But if you're going to clean the data manually anyway then you can split it yourself and cast/clean everything after

Comment: thank you! this is clear